# Correct spelling of demosaicing tag

Tags: bug

Can someone [fix the spelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaicing) of the tag [demozaicing] -> [demosaicing] ?

That's all I'm asking for, but I need to add this line to "meet our quality standards".

Comment: Looks like it's fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah sorry about that. I edited both questions with the wrong tag (which I'd created) to have the right spelling, and then the wrong one went away because of not being in use. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: I blame Mozilla for this. :)